# Editable JQuery DataTable

Tags: jquery, plugins, datatable, contenteditable

I am using JQuery dataTable plugin in my SharePoint site,  and would like to stick to it.

One of the requirement is to have a table with some cell being editable.

e.g. Some of the cells in a row being editable while others are not.

Is this possible to do with dataTable or any other plugin that can be used along with dataTable?

Answer (score 1):

try the datatable inline editing https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple